# What is __phello__ for in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

I imported `__phello__` in the terminal:

```
>>> import __phello__
Hello world!
```

What is `__phello__` for? Or is it just an Easter Egg?

Comment: Cool! Seems like an Easter egg: https://dimitrisjim.github.io/python-easter-eggs.html

Comment: Another one `from __phello__ import spam` :)

Comment: I had seen `import __hello__` before, not sure if this one differs in any way.

Comment: I see it's used in tests https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2de5097ba4c50eba90df55696a7b2e74c93834d4/Lib/test/test_importlib/frozen/test_loader.py#L37

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal I think both will work in [python 3](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/63298930fb531ba2bb4f23bc3b915dbf1e17e9e1/Python/frozen.c#L40)

Comment: They both seem to print "Hello world..." in Python 2 and "Hello world!" in Python 3

Comment: Also try `import this`, `import antigravity` and if you hate significant whitespace try `from __future__ import braces`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just an **Easter Egg in Python**. The file can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/__phello__.foo.py) and [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/63298930fb531ba2bb4f23bc3b915dbf1e17e9e1/Python/frozen.c), one of them is a helper file, the other one is the module.

Answer (score -1):

It’s a joke, it makes for a notably short hello world program in a vanilla installation. This is a thing that some people can get very competitive about...